# Generate symbols according to PDF (Probability Density Function) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, distribution, probability-density

In **Matlab** I've got a binomial PDF already defined where the set of possible events are 0-255. I would like to generate symbols, from 0-255, according to that PDF. How can I do that?

This is the code used in order to generate the PDF:

```
x=0:255; %range of possible values
m=255;
b=0.06245;
y=binopdf(x,m,b); %generates a binomial distribution
```

When plotting "y" I can see that most of the times the symbol that the source will generate will be between 9 to 23. Again, how can I design that symbol source? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
result = binornd(m,b,R,C);
```

to generate an `R` x `C` matrix of random values drawn from an (`m`,`b`) binomial distribution.

---

If you then plot the histogram

```
hist(result(:),-.5:255.5)
```

you can check that (for `R` and/or `C` large enough) the obtained values follow the desired binomial distribution.

Comment: I had already tried that function. But I was using it in the wrong way. Thanks!